# How to assign formula to an anonymous shape?

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

I'm trying to assign a formula to an object but I'm getting errors every time. The main point is that each time I am copying an image I need to assign a formula to the newly posted item. Indeed, I don`t have a specific shape name for it so I can use. Any suggestions?

```
  Dim sh As Shape
  Set sh = ActiveSheet.range("A" & Last_row ).Shape
  sh.DrawingObject.Formula = "=IMAGE" & Last_row
```

Comment: What is `.DrawingObject` and what is a `.Formula` in this context? More importantly, what is the Error you are getting? Could it be "Application defined or object-defined error" (like your `sh` doesn't have a `DrawingObject`)?

Comment: The formula is something like "=IMAGE1". The image is a name which is defined previously. drawingobject is the picture which is pasted as a drawingobject. I just don`t know how to call the shape which is placed inside a range without using its name.

Comment: Are you pasting the shape via code?  If Yes then it right after the paste you can use `Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't identify a shape by using a range reference directly. What this example does is to look though all the shapes in a designated sheet ... and it finds the first shape where the top left corner of the shape is in the cell specified (ie. C2 for this example) ... and it returns that shape so that a formula can be assigned to it (in this example "=B1"). You should be able to take this and extend it for what you're trying to do.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AssignShapeFormulaExample()
    Dim vShape As Shape
    Dim vRange As Range
    Dim vSheet As Worksheet

    ' Setup objects for the active sheet and an example cell (where a shape exists)
    Set vSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set vRange = vSheet.Range("C2")

    Set vShape = FirstShapeInCell(vSheet, vRange)

    If Not (vShape Is Nothing) Then
        vShape.DrawingObject.Formula = "=B1"
    End If

End Sub

Function FirstShapeInCell(vSheet As Worksheet, vRange As Range) As Shape
    Dim vShape As Shape
    Dim vShapeTopLeft As Range
    Dim vIntersect As Range

    ' Loop though all shapes in the designated sheet
    For Each vShape In vSheet.Shapes
        ' Setup a range that contains the top left corner of the shape
        With vShape
            Set vShapeTopLeft = vSheet.Cells(.TopLeftCell.Row, .TopLeftCell.Column)
        End With
        'See whether the shape in the range specified as an input parameter
        Set vIntersect = Application.Intersect(vRange, vShapeTopLeft)
        If Not (vIntersect Is Nothing) Then
            Set FirstShapeInCell = vShape
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```